# jQuery sliding effects moves the text in background

Tags: jquery, html

I need to display some items and those items must get hidden if clicked.I have tried the same using below script :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#p1").css("color", "red")
        .slideUp(2000)

    });
});
</script>
```

But the issue is when the button overlaps/ slides over the text there is a feel that text is also getting moved up.

> How to restrict the same movement of the text?

A Demo implementation of the same is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/8t6rnj6L/).

Thanks

Comment: Side note: When using `jsFiddle`, place your code in the right boxes. Also there are page elements that are not necessary, like `head`, `script`, `body`, etc.

Comment: you have written text in tag you are sliding. That is why text is also shifting.

Comment: @MelanciaUK yes just copied entire thing over there :)..thank you for suggestion for nxt time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The slide up of the text is caused by either the margin or padding of the `p`.  If you set these to 0 then the text won't move:

```
p {margin:0; padding:0;}
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/peteng/8t6rnj6L/4/)

Answer (score 2):

It's all cause your `p` has margin and with `slideUp` it decreases as height of an element decrease. |This causes your effect, so all you need is just add css

```
p{
  margin: 0;
}
```

and it will be ok

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8t6rnj6L/1/)